# Как работать с mysql на nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mysql

Есть такой код

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '******.mysql.mchost.ru',
    user     : '******_kopkan',
    password : '*****',
    database : '*****_chat'
});

    var q1 = 'SELECT * FROM log WHERE 1 = 1';
    connection.query(q1, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) console.log(err);;
        console.log('Added player');
    });
```

В консоли возвращается ошибка  Error:connection ETIMEDOUT, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был подобный баг, который решился заменой коннекшна на пул:

```
var mysql = require("mysql"),
      cMysql = mysql.createPool({
      database : 'dbase',
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'user',
      password : '12121212',
      connectionLimit: 100
    });
cMysql.getConnection(function(err,conn){
  if(err){
    console.log("MYSQL: can't get connection from pool:",err)
  }else {
    conn.query("SELECT   * FROM table WHERE 1",
       function(er,rows){
          if(er){
          conn.release();
          console.log("MYSQL: ERROR: ",err);
            } else {
          conn.release();
              // make someting with rows
            }
       });
  }
});
```

Коннекшн требует постоянного мониторинга активности подключения, а пул сам это контролирует, рекомендую.